# How to structure a JSON call

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an endpoint which I call with Axios and the response looks like (for example):

```
items: [
{
url: "https://api.example1...",
expirationDate: "2019-11-15T00:00:00+01:00"
},
{
url: "https://api.example2...",
expirationDate: "2019-12-20T00:00:00+01:00"
},
{
url: "https://api.example3...",
expirationDate: "2020-01-17T00:00:00+01:00"
},
```

...and so on.

If I go to one of the url:s in the browser the structure of the JSON is:

```
fooBar: {
    url: "https://api.foo...",
    id: "123",
    type: "INDEX",
    source: "Foobar",
    quotes: {
        url: "https://api.bar..."
    }
},
```

I need to get the quotes of the two first url:s in items:[] dynamically because they will disappear when the 'expirationDate' is older than today's date.
How can this be achieved? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the requirements correctly you need to:

- get the list of items
- get item details for first two items (to extract links to quotes)
- get quotes for first two items

You can use promise chaining to execute these operations maintaining the order:

```
const getQuotes = (item) => axios.get(item.url)
  .then(resp => axios.get(resp.data.fooBar.quotes.url));

axios.get('/items') // here should be the url that you use to get items array
  .then(resp => resp.data.slice(0, 2).map(getQuotes))
  .then(quotes => Promise.all(quotes))
  .then(quotes => {
    console.log(quotes);
  });
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I´m getting 'resp.data.slice is not a function'. Maybe because my 'axios.get()' is calling our backend and 'data' is the endpoint to the API? My original axios call looks like (example): `axios.get('https://backend-stage.example/v1/economy', {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: {'endpoint': 'v2/foo/bar/options-views'},
  }),`

Comment: Judging from the error message the endpoint that you hit to get items returns not an array but something different, probably an object. I would suggest inspecting the response (`resp`) structure and adjusting the path to the array before slicing, i.e `resp.your.path.to.items.slice(0, 2)...`

Answer (score 0):

Please find my proposal below. I gave two examples. You can get the whole `quotes` object, or just the URL inside the `quotes` object. 
This is just a console log, but you can easily ie. append this data to a `div` in the html or pass this URL to some other function.

```
$(function() {
  const address = 'https://api.example1...';

  function loadQuotes() {
    $.ajax({
      url: address,
      dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(response) {
      response.forEach(el => {
        console.log(`el.quotes`);
        // or if you want to be more specific console.log(`el.quotes.url`);
      });
    });
  }

  loadQuotes();
});
```

If these are nested objects, just append `fooBar`.

For example change the `.done` part to:

```
.done(function(response) {
let qqq = response.quotes
      quotes.forEach(el => {
        console.log(`el.quotes`);
        // or if you want to be more specific console.log(`el.quotes.url`);
      });
```